# Why does summing joint probabilities with respect to one variable give probabilities in terms of the other?

Tags: probability, marginal-distribution

I'm trying to understand how taking the summation with respect to $y$ gives me something in terms of $x.$ Specifically why:

$$\sum_{y} P_{XY}(x,y) = P_X(x)?$$

Answer (score 3):

By definition:

$$P_{Y|X}(y,x)=\frac {P_{XY}(x,y)}{P_{X}(x)} $$

Using the definition above:

$$ \sum_y P_{XY}(x,y)=\sum_y {P_{Y|X}(y,x)}{P_{X}(x)} = P_{X}(x) \sum_y {P_{Y|X}(y,x)}=P_{X}(x)$$

In other words, it's the marginal distribution so you're ignoring $y$